# Ckeditor - how to indent multiple times

Tags: ckeditor

I have a client that wants to be able to indent multiple times. This sort of things works in Word which is what they are use to. Specifically, they want to be able to indent bullets more than once.

From what I can tell CKEditor doesn't allow this... I'm assuming because it is using UL and LI tags which doesn't have an easy way to do this.

Does anyone know if CKeditor can do this?

I'm looking for something to give the output like this:

`<ul>
    <li>Test</li>
    <ul>
        <ul>
            <li>sdfdsf</li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</ul>`

Not like this

`<ul>
    <li>Test</li>
    <ul>
        <li>sdfdsf</li>
    </ul>
</ul>`

[image: Example image]

Comment: Yes ckeditor can do this with a addon (http://ckeditor.com/addon/indent) via buttons, or when you manually edit the source.

Answer (score 0):

Yes ckeditor can do this with an addon (http://ckeditor.com/addon/indent) via buttons, or when you manually edit the source like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>1. Level</li>
    <ul>
         <li>2. Level</li>
         <ul>
             <li>3. Level</li>
         </ul>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

and so on...

Comment: Yes this does indent however it won't let me double indent. Please see my updated post.

Comment: That is correct, but I do not see why you would need to double indent. Can't you work with css to make more indent space?

Comment: If there is a way to do that by hitting the tab key or the indent key multiple times, then sure. If you use Word or Evernote, they both work this way.

Comment: you could, for example add object styles for lists that enable the user to add more intend or change the bullet style. I still do not see why someone would want to make 2 indent steps, when there is only one needed. Ckeditor is not word or Evernote and users should be aware of that, no matter how close you can get it to work like word or evernote. At least I made the experience several times that it is better to take time to advice users than to take time to make ckeditor work like word. It never will 100%.

Comment: I'm totally with you but unfortunately users are used to doing something in a very specific way especially when they are generating something that a client will see.

Comment: Best is to be in a position to reject customers demand due to technical impossibility. Users are used to learn new tools as they get them, they once learned Word, too. Word is not an intuitive tool, they are just used to it. Just because they used Word for several decades, does not mean they can expect any other tool to work exactly like Word. Especially when Microsoft spend lots of resources to make their software and Document Specifications work in a way that compatibility with third partys is very hard to impossible.